# Como ingresar mas de 3 colores en un grafico velocimetro de POWER BI?

Tags: powerbi

lo que busco es realizar una grafica en power bi , de tipo velocimetro, que me permita ingresar mas de 3 colores. actualmente estoy usando estas gráficas que se ven en la foto, pero solo me permite hasta 3 colores. pero que gráfica de tipo velocímetro podría usar para que me admita mas colores?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

No recuerdo haber visto una visualización en forma de velocímetro que lo permite. Si recuerdo que el Bullet Chart si permitía como 5 estados.

Espero que aun te sirva